# Why and how do red bone marrow concentrations in humans change during traditional aging?

Tags: human-physiology, bone-biology, bone

I have found several pictures that suggest this is the case.  As for peer reviewed papers I've found plenty of papers hypothesizing and testing as to the why of changes in populations of HSCs, a few on quantitative changes in MSCs, but none explaining why red bone marrow would become less active hematopoietically in long bones before flat bones.